# Is there a way to export a flextable object to Excel?

Tags: r, excel, flextable

I want to try export a flextable object to an excel spreadsheet, but I can't find any solutions. According to this documentation (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/index.html), the package allows users to export formattable objects to pdfs, docs, and ppts.

One work around is to save it to one of these formats and then save it to an excel spreadsheet, but I'm looking for a solution that is less hackish and also scalable to many tables.

Comment: I don't really see how `csv` would work... so much of flextable is about formatting, and CSV files by definition do not have any formatting.

Comment: I've edited the original question to specify excel.

Comment: Save it to an excel spreadsheet how? Like as a formatted spreadsheet? Or a picture pasted into a spreadsheet? A csv file is just a plain text file; the comma separation is more a convention than anything specific to the file type

Comment: I've removed the other mentions of CSV from your question.

Comment: As a formatted spreadsheet. Package 'xlsx' allows R users to export data to excel with formmating. The question is whether this is possible for formattable.

Answer (score 1):

Update (Jan/2023): Meanwhile a package appeared called `YesSiR` from Sebastian with a nice function called `exportxlsx()`

Installation:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("Sebastien-Le/YesSiR")
library(YesSiR) # to export a flextable into MS Excel: exportxlsx() function
```

There is a nice example available:

```
## Not run: 
ft <- flextable::flextable(head(mtcars))
ft
# color some cells in blue
ft <- flextable::bg(ft, i=ft$body$dataset$disp>200, j=3, bg = "#7ed6df", part = "body")
# color a few cells in yellow
ft <- flextable::bg(ft, i=ft$body$dataset$vs==0, j=8, bg = "#FCEC20", part = "body")
# export your flextable as a .xlsx in the current working directory
exportxlsx(ft, path = "X:/temp_del/excel_file.xlsx")
```

Maybe that helps.